# can't load loadLibrary,Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6

Tags: android, ffmpeg

When I use `System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg-neon")`,there is a warning

```
libffmpeg-neon.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix
```

and an erro

```
libc Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10203
```

The source from https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg.I build it on Unubtu-14.04.3-64bit,NDK-r10e

Comment: You use Android Studio?

Comment: eclipse，targetSdkVersion 17,sdk tools 24.3.3,platform-tools 22.

Comment: It's my phone is ART model？